# css gradient: calculate second stop color

Tags: html, css

I'd like to be able to be able to calculate the second hex color of a button background gradient based on the first (see sample below).

So I would get the first color via a color picker from the user and get that using Javascript (e.g. #ededed in the sample below). Based on the first color, I would like to use JS to calculate an offset which generates the second color and the gradient effect (#dfdfdf in the sample below). The color shift would always be the same, just the input and output hex colors would differ.

Is there a formular or function I could use? thanks!

```
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
```

Comment: We need more detail, you've only provided very vague details.

Comment: check out this link - cool http://gradients.glrzad.com/ maybe you could nick some code ;)

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want to do. Do you want to do this without JS? But then, you say the user uses a color picker so you are using JS. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know, you're using the "old" format for `-webkit-gradient`. You should update to using this instead:

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf)
```

Now, on to the actual problem, you haven't specified how the second colour should be calculated. I'll assue you want it a shade lighter, considering the example you gave. In this case, you can do this:

```
var color = "#ededed";
var components = [
    (255-(255-parseInt(color.substr(1,2),16))/2).toString(16),
    (255-(255-parseInt(color.substr(3,2),16))/2).toString(16),
    (255-(255-parseInt(color.substr(5,2),16))/2).toString(16)
];
if(components[0].length < 2) components[0] = "0"+components[0];
if(components[1].length < 2) components[1] = "0"+components[1];
if(components[2].length < 2) components[2] = "0"+components[2];
var out = "#"+components[0]+components[1]+components[2];
```

This will give you the colour that is halfway between the source colour and pure white (effectively overlaying a 50%-opacity white over it). To get a darker shade, just remove the `255-(255-` bit and the corresponding `)`.

EDIT: On second thoughts, just use a solid background with a transparent gradient:

```
background:#ededed -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but my approach would be to use RGB values instead of hex.  Then use variables to hold your two color values.  The second variable could be calculated based of the value of the first one (as in, @color2 = @color1 + 2) or whatever.